# Unwanted substitution of bool overload when trying to use sfinae overload

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

The answer to this question exists exactly almost, but I could not find it.

The code below as expected does not work due to the implicit conversion of integer type  to bool.

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value &&
                                              std::is_signed<T>::value &&
                                              !std::is_same<T, bool>::value, T>::type>
inline void test(T) { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }

inline void test(bool) { std::cout << "bool" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    test(int());
    test(bool());
}
```

To fix this I've tried :

- priority tagging
- converting bool overload to specialization
- `std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, bool>::value, T>::type>` on bool overload

but all with no effect(either compilation error, or two bool calls).

Is there any way to separate this two overloads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, for the 1st overload, the 2nd template parameter, which is declared as a non-type parameter, can't be deduced and makes the 1st overload [can't be selected](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PGrPItTQdnWITJUs) at all.

You can specify a default value for the 2nd template parameter. e.g.

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value &&
                                              std::is_signed<T>::value &&
                                              !std::is_same<T, bool>::value, T>::type = 0>
//                                                                                    ^^^
inline void test(T) { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VnZznXIuXdvsNrOp)

Comment: Thank you, saved my day! 
The problem, of course, is the lack of typename =

Comment: I would prefer `std::enable_if_t<cond<T>::value, int> = 0` over `typename = std::enable_if_t<cond<T>::value>`: Allow other overloads (as floating point), and avoid possible hijack (`test<bool, void>(true)`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I just revised it. :)